# In a custom GUI skin what is a scaled background and how does it work?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a custom GUI skin and one of the settings under `Box` → `Normal` is "Scaled Backgrounds". What is this and how does it work? I can't find it in the documentation anywhere.

[image]

UPD: I'm making a custom `EditorWindow`. **NOT for a game**. So I load skin setting for buttons, labels, textinputs for `GUILayout` and `EditorGUILayout`.

I tried to load textures into these slots, but nothing happened, whereas "Background" loads successfully

Comment: Why not try it out yourself? Worse case scenario, you have to change it back to the original values.

Comment: @TreytenCarey thanks for your comment about nothing....Do you think I didn't try and just came here 'cause I'm too lazy to try?

Comment: @Draco18s  I'm making a custom EditorWindow and that's settings for it. Not for a game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaled backgrounds are used when you're using a **high-resolution** monitor. It is actually being mentioned in the documentation and related to GUIStyleState.

**GUIStyleState**

> Specialized values for the given states used by GUIStyle objects.

See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyleState.html

**ScaledBackgrounds**

> Background images used by this state when on a high-resolution screen. It should either be left empty, or contain a single image that is exactly twice the resolution of background. This is only used by the editor. The field is not copied to player data, and is not accessible from player code.

So you won't notice any difference unless you're using a high-res monitor.

*For reference: https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=scaled+background&type=*

Comment: It's really weird and confusing)) I don't quite understand why this field is an array. For the future functionality? Over-engineering?))

Comment: It's probably just something about their internal implementation. For example, in this file https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled/blob/a2111d9e5a280d7740d015ab73e217119973f770/UnityEngine/UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.StyleSheets/VisualElementStylesData.cs at line 435, they explicitly target the first element. So it probably isn't meant to be filled with more than one texture. Using an array does indeed seem weird, but that's unity :)

Comment: `in this file they explicitly target the first element` - yeap, I saw this and that's why I didn't understand why it's an array)) Well, thank you for the answer.